# Nested Bool Always Returns Nil

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having a problem with this Swift function and although I'm sure the solution is fairly straightforward I cannot figure out what is wrong. Here is the code:

```
static func isArtist(user:FIRUser) -> Bool? {
    var artist: Bool?
    database.child("users").child(user.uid).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        artist = true //retrieves bool, simplified for example
    }) { (error) in
        print("isArtist - data could not be retrieved - EXCEPTION: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }
    return artist
}
```

The function returns `nil` every time, when logically I would think it would return `true`. Is this a problem with nested functions? How can I return content in the nested function? The database is the implementation of the Swift Firebase SDK, and the function should only return nil if no such object can be retrieved (for this example, if `artist` is nil). Thanks.

Comment: Your function returns immideatly, while closure looks like continue executing in other thread. You are assigning artist = true in callback, already out of function scope.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning data from async call in Swift function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203556/returning-data-from-async-call-in-swift-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `completionBlock:` to handle your situation , The reason why this is going to return you a `nil` is because you have declared your `artist` variable as `optional` , and it takes some time to retrieve data from any backend(asynchronous calls) thus executing `return artist` even before you could retrieve some value from database:-

Use :-

```
static func isArtist(user:FIRUser, completionBlock : ((isArtistBool : Bool)-> Void)) {
    database.child("users").child(user.uid).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
             completionBlock(isArtistBool : true) //returns Bool in completionHnadler

        }) { (error) in

           print("isArtist - data could not be retrieved - EXCEPTION: " + error.localizedDescription)
          }

}
```

When you would call your function `isArtist` :-

```
isArtist(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser, completionBlock : {(isArtistBool) in 
 //Will return `isArtistBool` in completionHandler
 ..//rest of the code
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember, you are fetching value of artist Asynchronously. It means the data might be available in near future but not sure when. so, this Asynchronous function runs in background thread and the programme continue to execute, hence returns nil.

```
database.child("users").child(user.uid).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        // this is asynchronous block. snapshot is available in near future.
    })
```

so instead of `return`  use your completion block:

```
database.child("users").child(user.uid).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
             completionBlock(isArtistBool : true)
        })
```

and yeah, dont forget to remove `-> Bool` form the function, you dont need that when you are using `completionBlock`.

when using completion block your function signatures becomes like this:

```
isArtist(user: FIRUser, completionBlock: () -> FIRUser)) {

}
```

you can call this function as:

```
SomeClass.isArtist(user: FIRUser, completionBlock: () -> FIRUser){

  // your  user is available here after the value is fetched from firebase.
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help!